# How to limit 10 requests per second for 3 urls(including all 3) from Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a third party service to get RSS feed and 2 other similar services through 3 url calls.

The service has a restriction of max 10 requests per second for all 3 urls. Means if there is no call for first url, remaining 2 urls can be called 10 times in total in a second. and if there are 3 calls for 2nd url then only 7 calls allowed for remaining 2 urls in a second. I am using Tomcat 7.

Couldn't find a way to get it done in spring. If anyone can give an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not very cliear what is your actual application requirement... Do you need to interval these calls so that you have ONLY 10 in a second, or you can execute them as quick as you can? Is there any error returned if you execute 11 calls per second? Better explain what you need to implement...

Comment: Try searching on [RateLimiter](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java) - I have seen similar questions here on SO where (a form of) `RateLimiter` provided a solution.

Comment: @davioooh : All 3 services belong to the same vendor and if we are sending more than 10 requests per second including all 3 services they are blocking us.

Answer (score 2):

I would introduce a CallLimiter spring bean - singleton. The bean should have a Queue - last 10 call time.

The bean can be added to all the 3 places where you need to call the remote API.

Before call check first time in the queue. 
If it's bigger than 1 second you can call the remote API and add current call time in the end of the queue. If it is less than 1 second just call `Thread.currentThread().wait(50);` (actually the wait time could be any you like) and repeat.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to some implementation level example.

Comment: There are neither link nor implementation. I just express an idea how to implement the requirement.